# sqlplus failed to connect local Oracle. Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a Oracle11g in Windows 2016 server.

1.Here is how I use the sqlplus

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sqlplus testuser1/Password1@orcl
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Nov 27 16:28:16 2019
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
ERROR:
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
Enter user-name:
```

2.tnsping failed as well

```
C:\Users\Administrator>tnsping orcl
TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 27-NOV-2019 16:29:39
Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Used parameter files:
C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Oracle11gg.mshome.net)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.mshome.net)))
TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

3.Here is the tnsnames file

```
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Oracle11gg.mshome.net)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.mshome.net)
    )
  )
```

4. some articles say i need to setup environment , but i don't know which one i should use...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `ping Oracle11gg.mshome.net` and `telnet Oracle11gg.mshome.net 1521`

Comment: @DmitryDemin, ping may not work, but telnet/nc to port 1521 will :)